# @Slf4j Lombok annotation not working with Java + Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, logging, slf4j, lombok

I'm fairly new to Java and trying to implement a logger with @Slf4j annotation provided by lombok. From my understanding it should be fairly simple, just provide the annotation to the class and it will create the method for that class but it seems to not work.

My code looks like this:

```
package MyApp;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("hello"); IDEA gives this error: Cannot resolve method 'info(String)'
    }
}
```

When trying to run the code i get this:
error: package org.slf4j does not exist
@Slf4j
^

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j:2.20.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.28'
    
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I have already tried enabling annotations.

Also, I saw this implementation working in another project and i tryed simply copying the dependencies, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The @Slf4j annotation is for another logging library. You have a dependency for Log4j library. Then you should use @Log4j Lombok annotation.

On the other hand if you want to use Slf4j then change the dependency to org.slf4j

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ as your IDE, please include lombok plugin also in your gradle file:

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.freefair.lombok

In case of Eclipse, you need to manually run the lombok jar file to resolve this issue.
Detailed description is available [here](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide)

Comment: Still the same:
error: package org.slf4j does not exist
@Slf4j

Comment: Revlis, Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Im using Intellij Idea